# Bouncy Castle FIPS Mode issue

Tags: java, bouncycastle, fips

Existing jars: bc-fips-1.0.0.jar, bcpkix-jdk15on-1.54.jar

Upgraded to: bc-fips-1.0.2.3.jar, bcpkix-jdk15on-1.69.jar and added dependent jar: bcutil-jdk15on-1.69.jar.

we are using ssl authentication with following properties

```
keystore.type=bcfks
keystore.type.compat=true

security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider
security.provider.2=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider BCFIPS
security.provider.3=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.4=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider

ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=SunX509
ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm=PKIX
```

Our application was working with no issues with old jars. After upgrade, it is failing with following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Integer.intValueExact()I
        at org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.CCMParameters.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.CCMParameters.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.ProvBCFKS$BCFIPSKeyStoreSpi.decryptData(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.ProvBCFKS$BCFIPSKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
```

The reason is org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Integer.intValueExact() is not present in bc-fips-1.0.2.3.jar. There is no compatible jar to address this issue.

Can anyone help fix this issue?

Comment: Odd. I'm looking at the private ctor of `CCMParameters` and it doesn't call `intValueExact`. Make sure you have a reliable source. The one I'm looking at is from Maven

Comment: Thanks @g00se for your reply, In the above case, constructor of CCMParameters from bcutil-jdk15on-1.69.jar is called which makes a call to intValueExact. This issue got resolved by removing bcpkix-jdk15on-1.69.jar and  bcutil-jdk15on-1.69.jar and adding bcpkix-fips-1.0.5.jar

Comment: Glad you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Probably I'm late to the party, but as I recall, KeyStorage must use PKIX algorithm in FIPS mode.
Documentation says that this line must be present in Java security file (or loaded dinamically):

```
ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=PKIX
```